# Android long string concatenament,

Tags: java, android, json, string

I have this methods :

```
private String  convertPolygonToJSON(Polygon p) {
        List<LatLng> points=p.getPoints();
        String s="[1,["+points.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {
            s=s+","+points.get(i);
        }
        s=s+"],{\"strokeColor\":\"#FF0000\",\"fillColor\":\"#00FFFF\"}]";
        return s;

}

private String  getJsonPolygones(List<Polygon> polys) {
        String s="";
        for (int i = 0; i < polys.size(); i++) {
            s=s+convertPolygonToJSON(polys.get(i))+",";

        }
        return s;
    }
```

that convert polygone to json String,
the problem is that the polgon has a lot of point and this function is called into a loop to convert List of polygons to final json.

I guess, it takes a lot of memory, I see alot of GC loggin and even after 15 minuts the loop does not end.

(I have a List of polygones ( 7xxx points, 4xxx points, 2xx points .....)

I'd like to know if there is an alternative to get this JSON.

Any help is welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: @npinti you can make that an answer

Comment: @Simo: I have added some more information below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since people tend to overlook comments, in your case, you are creating a new string object each time since strings are immutable. This will cause a lot of memory consumption and thus higher GC activity.

Using the [StringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) will allow you to efficiently concatenate strings as you go along without such memory overhead:

```
private String  convertPolygonToJSON(Polygon p) {
        List<LatLng> points=p.getPoints();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[1,["+points.get(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {
            sb.append(+ ","+points.get(i));
        }
        sb.append("],{\"strokeColor\":\"#FF0000\",\"fillColor\":\"#00FFFF\"}]");
        return sb.toString();

}
```

And similarly for the other method.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of String usage you have to use StringBuilder.
Apply to your code you obtain:

```
private String  convertPolygonToJSON(Polygon p) {
    List<LatLng> points = p.getPoints();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("[1,[");
    sb.append(points.get(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append(points.get(i));
    }
    sb.append("],{\"strokeColor\":\"#FF0000\",\"fillColor\":\"#00FFFF\"}]");
    return sb.toString();
}

private String  getJsonPolygones(List<Polygon> polys) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < polys.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(convertPolygonToJSON(polys.get(i)));
        sb.append(',');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

String class is immutable class, hence modifying a String requires more memory & CPU usage ( when repetition work is going on ).

For such operations, I suggest you to use [StringBuiler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [StringBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) Class.

These both are mutable class. Hence you can do String operations on them.